# New user can sudo to root in RHEL 6.10

Tags: rhel, security, sudo

I'm using a RHEL 6.10 and recently observed any new user can get sudo to root access by default.

I checked all sudoer files but no such reference, only a few users are configured there and that doesn't have any relations with the new users (such as common group).

We tried testing by creating multiple new user accounts and also with kerberos user account and found them all able to sudo2root without any reference in sudores.

Can you suggest any pointer for such configuration done system wide.

Comment: Can you post your sudoers file? Are there any files in the /etc/sudoers.d directory? What default group are your users created with? Does the root user have a password?

Comment: Unfortunately, I won't be able to publish file here. There are no files in sudoers.d directory and users are created with their own group same as the user name. User's doesn't have root password. As I mentioned I created few users as below: 1st user:  user1(username)   user1(group)      2nd user: user2(username)    user2(group)

Comment: Near the end of the sudoers file, is there an include statement? It will start with #.
Other than that, how many non-comment lines are in your sudoers file?

Comment: ## This file must be edited with the 'visudo' command.

## Host Aliases

## User Aliases
User_Alias SYSADM = +sysadmin, %sysadmin, +xyznadmin, xyznmon
User_Alias LINUX1 = linux1

## Command Aliases
Cmnd_Alias LOAD_KERBEROS_DATA = /usr/sbin/kdb5_util load, /var/kerberos/krb5kdc/slave_datatrans

# Defaults specification

#
# Refuse to run if unable to disable echo on the tty.
#
Defaults   !visiblepw

Comment: #
# Preserving HOME has security implications since many programs
# use it when searching for configuration files. Note that HOME
# is already set when the the env_reset option is enabled, so
# this option is only effective for configurations where either
# env_reset is disabled or HOME is present in the env_keep list.
#
Defaults    always_set_home

Defaults    requiretty
Defaults: xyzgo !requiretty
xyzgo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
xyzgoki ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
root ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL

Comment: Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    env_keep =  "COLORS DISPLAY HOSTNAME HISTSIZE INPUTRC KDEDIR LS_COLORS"
Defaults    env_keep += "MAIL PS1 PS2 QTDIR USERNAME LANG LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE"
Defaults    env_keep += "LC_COLLATE LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_MEASUREMENT LC_MESSAGES"
Defaults    env_keep += "LC_MONETARY LC_NAME LC_NUMERIC LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE"
Defaults    env_keep += "LC_TIME LC_ALL LANGUAGE LINGUAS _XKB_CHARSET XAUTHORITY"

Comment: # Adding HOME to env_keep may enable a user to run unrestricted
# commands via sudo.
#
# Defaults   env_keep += "HOME"

Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

## Allow root to run any commands anywhere
root    ALL=(ALL)       ALL

## Allow UNIX sysadmins to run all.
SYSADM        ALL=(ALL)       ALL

## Linux1 user
LINUX1      ALL=NOPASSWD: LOAD_KERBEROS_DATA
xyzscloud   ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
## Allows people in group wheel to run all commands
# %wheel        ALL=(ALL)       ALL

Comment: ## Same thing without a password
# %wheel        ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL

## Read drop-in files from /etc/sudoers.d (the # here does not mean a comment)
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d

Comment: Have one of the users run the command `sudo -l`

Comment: sudo -lUuser1
Matching Defaults entries foruser1 on this host:
    !visiblepw, always_set_home, requiretty, env_reset, env_keep="COLORS DISPLAY HOSTNAME HISTSIZE INPUTRC KDEDIR LS_COLORS", env_keep+="MAIL PS1 PS2 QTDIR USERNAME
    LANG LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE", env_keep+="LC_COLLATE LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_MEASUREMENT LC_MESSAGES", env_keep+="LC_MONETARY LC_NAME LC_NUMERIC LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE",
    env_keep+="LC_TIME LC_ALL LANGUAGE LINGUAS _XKB_CHARSET XAUTHORITY", secure_path=/sbin\:/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin

Useruser1 may run the following commands on this host:
    (ALL) ALL

Comment: @Vikas please [edit] your post to add information. Use code formatting to show file contents and command output: https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to follow, but there are still a few interesting things here.
 `sudo -l user1`
Matching Defaults entries foruser1 on this host:
!visiblepw, always_set_home, requiretty, env_reset, env_keep="COLORS DISPLAY HOSTNAME HISTSIZE INPUTRC KDEDIR LS_COLORS", env_keep+="MAIL PS1 PS2 QTDIR USERNAME LANG LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE", env_keep+="LC_COLLATE LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_MEASUREMENT LC_MESSAGES", env_keep+="LC_MONETARY LC_NAME LC_NUMERIC LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE", env_keep+="LC_TIME LC_ALL LANGUAGE LINGUAS _XKB_CHARSET XAUTHORITY", secure_path=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin 
**Useruser1 may run the following commands on this host:
 
(ALL) ALL**

That is the issue. I think it comes from this line in your sudoers:
`##Linux1
user LINUX1 ALL=NOPASSWD: LOAD_KERBEROS_DATA` 
Is that what is in your sudoers file? Something, perhaps a typeo, is allowing your users users to get the (ALL) ALL value.

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to format data, but not able to do so, I guess it will take some time for me to learn formatting here. Anyway, I see this line as below:


## Linux1 user <br/>
LINUX1      ALL=NOPASSWD: LOAD_KERBEROS_DATA <br/>

Comment: User_Alias SYSADM = +sysadmin, %sysadmin, +vinciadmin, vincimon   <br/>
User_Alias LINUX1 = linux1   <br/>
<br/>       <br/>
Cmnd_Alias LOAD_KERBEROS_DATA = /usr/sbin/kdb5_util load, /var/kerberos/krb5kdc/slave_datatrans <br/>


Defaults   !visiblepw  <br/>

Defaults    always_set_home  <br/>

Defaults    requiretty  <br/>
Defaults: arago !requiretty  <br/>
arago ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL  <br/>
aragoki ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL  <br/>
root ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL  <br/>

Comment: Defaults    env_reset  <br/>
Defaults    env_keep =  "COLORS DISPLAY HOSTNAME HISTSIZE INPUTRC KDEDIR LS_COLORS"  <br/>
Defaults    env_keep += "MAIL PS1 PS2 QTDIR USERNAME LANG LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE"  <br/>
Defaults    env_keep += "LC_COLLATE LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_MEASUREMENT LC_MESSAGES"  <br/>
Defaults    env_keep += "LC_MONETARY LC_NAME LC_NUMERIC LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE"  <br/>
Defaults    env_keep += "LC_TIME LC_ALL LANGUAGE LINGUAS _XKB_CHARSET XAUTHORITY"  <br/>

Comment: Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin  <br/>

root    ALL=(ALL)       ALL  <br/>

SYSADM        ALL=(ALL)       ALL   <br/>

LINUX1      ALL=NOPASSWD: LOAD_KERBEROS_DATA  <br/>
surecloud   ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL  <br/>

Comment: @VikasThakur please [EDIT YOUR QUESTION](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/529207/edit) and stop putting information into comments.

Comment: ScottieH your suggested pair of lines could equally be a single commented line `##Linux1 user LINUX1 ALL=NOPASSWD: LOAD_KERBEROS_DATA`. We just don't know. "_It's a bit hard to follow_" - no, it's impossible to follow.